# Return API result to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm calling an API that returns a JSON string as below

```
{"ItemNumber":"5542","MD5Key":"md5key"}
```

What I want to do is to show these values in my View and this is what I have at the moment. The error is that my code is returning a View that not exists and my Model MD5 string is null, just the values that I fill directly are ok (ItemNumber, File).

Model

```
public class FileUpload
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Number is required")]
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public string MD5Key { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upsert([FromForm] FileUpload obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] p1 = null;
            using (var fs1 = files[0].OpenReadStream())
            {
                using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                    p1 = ms1.ToArray();
                }
            }
            obj.File = p1;
            obj.ItemNumber = 5542;
        }
    }

    await _cuRepo.CreateAsync("https://apiurl/method", obj.File, obj.ItemNumber);
    return View(obj);
    //This is returning a view Upsert, and obj.File, obj.ItemNumber are ok, just MD5 is null.
}
```

Repository (The main problem should be this)

```
public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(string url, byte[] file, int number)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("header", "aaaaaa");

        using (var content =
             new MultipartFormDataContent("Upload----" + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(number.ToString()), "ItemNumber");
            content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(file)), "File", "filename.txt");

            using (var message = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
            {
                var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //input has the JSON string

                if (input != null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to return to my View after the post and populate my Model with the API call results?

Comment: so 'https://apiurl/method' is returning this 

{"ItemNumber":"5542","MD5Key":"md5key"} therefore md5 has value is returning to you ? so you want to get that md5 value and return from this end pount ? or you want to calculate the md5 value within your code.

Comment: @GonzalesGokhan apiurl/method is returning that JSON, what I want to do after that is to set those values to my model and return that model to my view to show the result in a form controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would create a new class for reponse object from from API. It is not a good idea to return user input to page. Better to have your own view model. (i use Json.NET nuget package for deserialization.

```
public class FileUploadResponse
{
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string MD5Key { get; set; }
}
```

then deserisalize the response json to FileUploadResponse object

```
FileUploadResponse fileUploadResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileUploadResponse>(input);
```

and return that instead of bool

```
return fileUploadResponse
```

you have to change the method signature too

```
public async Task<FileUploadResponse> CreateAsync(string url, byte[] file, int number)
```

then finally in your *controller* . you can

```
var response=await _cuRepo.CreateAsync("https://apiurl/method", obj.File, obj.ItemNumber);
return View(response);
```

Comment: This is now returning the values to the view however, the return View(response) is returning to the view Upsert which not exists

Comment: I fixed adding return View("Index", response) and now it works however it's adding /Upsert to my url, is there a way to avoid that? Just keeping mypage.com/FileUpload instead of mypage.com/FileUpload/Upsert

Comment: can you not override the route with [HttpPost("/FileUpload")] ? i think Your default configuration is {ControllerName}/{MethodName} . you can read about Attribute routing 

https://exceptionnotfound.net/an-overview-of-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0-mvc/